# Highlight anything in LaTeX article

Tags: highlighting

I'm looking for a package/command that will highlight *anything* I wrap with it. Currently the closest thing I've found is `soul` but it has many shortcomings:

- No sectioning highlighting
- No automatic footnotes highlighting
- No `\cite` highlighting unless wrapped in an `\mbox{}`
- No `\citep` highlighting

Here's an example article where these points can be seen:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=cyan, pdfborder={0 0 0},}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\section{\hl{Title of a section}}

This is a line with no highlighting done.\\
\hl{This is a line where a citation \citep{Knuth86} appears.}
\hl{This is a line with a footnote\footnote{And this is the footnote that should also be automatically highlighted.} which I want highlighted.}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

where the `biblio.bib` file looks like:

```
@ARTICLE{Knuth86,
   author = {Knuth, D. E.},
    title = "{The TeXbook}",
    year = 1986,
}
```

If you try to compile it with the usual:

```
pdflatex "%f" && bibtex "%e" && pdflatex "%f" && pdflatex "%f"
```

command, it will fail for all the reasons I gave above. Isn't there something that *just works*?

---

**Edit**

The accepted answer comes close but after finding out about `latexdiff` (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) I actually switched to using that app instead of manually highlighting text.

Comment: Upvoting the question to reward the OP for his participation in the useful comment dialog, ending with his endorsement of @cfr 's analysis.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*This is only a partial solution* **and it doesn't really work across linebreaks well**, but if you replace the highlight commands with

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\hl}[1][yellow]{on line, arc=7pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black,
  before upper={\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},boxrule=1pt, boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,
  right=6pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt}
```

then I think that the highlighting almost works the way that the OP wants it to:

[image]

The main issue is that the `\footnote` does not appear at all. (The OP might also complain about `\citep` but as the package specifications for this seem to be missing I just used `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and carried on.)

You can get the footnote to display properly, with the required highlighting, by manually using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`:

```
\hl{This is a line with a footnote\footnotemark which I want highlighted.}
\footnotetext{\hl{And this is the footnote that should also be 
      automatically highlighted.}}
```

This now produces the missing footnote:

[image]

The OP no doubt would prefer the footnotes to be cared for automatically. I think that this should be possible to arrange, although multiple footnotes in a section of highlighted text might cause problems. I don't have time to do this now but if no one else has found a solution I will try and look at this tomorrow.

Comment: _The OP no doubt would prefer the footnotes to be cared for automatically_, I would :) I'll keep the question open until tomorrow then. Thank you!

Comment: Andrew: please see edited answer, I've added the `natbib` package.

Comment: @Gabriel Sorry, the idea that I had for extending this doesn't work. Worse than this, my proposed solution is fundamentally flawed because it does not cope with line breaks in the highlighted text. Given this I think that that the only honourable thing to do is for me to delete my answer. I will do this once you have had a chance to read this comment.

Comment: Please don't delete your answer, it came very close of being a complete answer to the question and it got enough votes to ensure people found it useful. As I said in a cmmt above I'm accepting your answer and I'll present a caveat in the original question mentioning `latexdiff`.

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks, I leave it up then. I am a big fan of latexdiff as well. It works particularly well when combined with git for version (and collaborator:) control.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful of `stomach commands` in section titles, use the optional argument. This works. You also have an issue with `\citep{}` from "natbib", which you missed from your MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=cyan, pdfborder={0 0 0},}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\section[title of section]{\hl{Title of a section}}

This is a line with no highlighting done.\\
\hl{This is a line where a citation \protect\cite{Knuth86} appears.}
\hl{This is a line with a footnote\footnote{\protect\hl{And this is the footnote that should also be automatically highlighted.}} which I want highlighted.}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{Knuth86} D.E. Knuth, The TeXbook, 1986
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Check this [article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88garcia.pdf) for some very goods tips, about `hyperref's` commands.

Comment: Adding `[]` before the section title works in getting it highlighted, thanks. As for the rest I don't know if I might be missing something but the `\protect` command makes a bit of a mess by changing how anything beyond the `\hl{}` that follows is handled. Also what I want is to _not_ have to jump through these loops in order to get `\hl` to work. I want a command that will _just work_ without needing any extra commands.

Comment: @Gabriel The "I want a command that will _just work_ without needing any extra commands" part, is not possible. What you asking actually is typographically abhorent and unsurprising no-one has spent time to develop it. You might have a bit of better luck with XelaTeX and fontspec, but again is not instant cream soda.

Comment: Yiannis: the _not possible_ part Im' pretty sure it's not true. LaTeX is a programming language and I see no reason why this command could not exist. The _typographically abhorent_ bit I can understand but I'm not after such a command to use in finished documents. This would be useful when one needs to highlight changes say to show a co-author quickly what has changed in a new version of an article/chapter/etc.

Comment: And still my issue with `\protect` remains. If I use `\hl{This is a line where a citation \protect\cite{Knuth86} appears.}` it will prevent _appears_ from being highlighted even though it is wrapped inside the `\hl` command.

Comment: `\hl{This is a line where a citation} \protect\cite{Knuth86} \hl{appears.}`. For co-authors easier to annotate a pdf over the web?

Comment: That's even less "just works-sy" :) I'm sorry, I don't quite follow your question, would you mind re-phrasing it?

Comment: @Gabriel This is surely an XY problem. There are much easier and more efficient ways to manage this workflow than the one you are looking for. You should not be marking up your changes *manually* in the first place. (I assume you are not editing the original `.tex` file but even so.) Use something like `latexdiff` to create a document highlighting the changes. If you really want to highlight them manually, then doing so in the PDF probably is the easiest solution.

Comment: That's very interesting @cfr, I wasn't aware of the XY problem and I surely wasn't aware of the existence of `latexdiff`. I've tried it now and it looks like just what I was attempting to do manually. I'll probably mark Andrew's answer as accepted tomorrow but your comment is really spot on. Thank you very much (and the rest of the guys who helped too of course).

Comment: Thanks for `\section[title of section]{\hl{Title of a section}}`, which solves exactly the problem I was having.